# Pick Timestamps in Certain Time Range From a DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

I have a bunch of DataFrames where I want to select only data that occurs at certain times during the day. Say, between 9am and 5pm. But the data starts before 9, and finishes after 5.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

start = pd.Timestamp("20170807 08:30-0400")
end = pd.Timestamp("20170807 17:30-0400")
index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=start, end=end, freq="10min")
data = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(55, 3))
columns = ["A", "B", "C"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
```

I could get the data I want by doing something like:

```
df[(df.index >= "20170807 09:00-0400") & (df.index <= "20170807 17:00-0400")]["A"]
```

But what I'd really like is an elegant method that doesn't depend on the date.

I.e. I'd love to be able to do:

```
df[(df.index >= "09:00-0400") & (df.index <= "17:00-0400")]["A"]
```

Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost!  It's nearly that easy.  Just use `between_time`.

```
df.between_time('08:00', '17:00')
```

To get only column `A`, append the above with `.loc[:, 'A']`

Comment: Thanks internet stranger. I felt like it had to be a thing.