# How can I select all dataframe entries between two times, when the time is a series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Here's some data:

```
my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'time': ["2024-1-1 09:00:00", "2024-1-1 15:00:00", "2024-1-1 21:00:00", "2024-1-2 09:00:00", "2024-1-2 15:00:00", "2024-1-2 21:00:00"],
                   'assists': [5, 7, 7, 9, 12, 9],
                   'rebounds': [11, 8, 10, 6, 6, 5],
                   'blocks': [4, 7, 7, 6, 5, 8]})
```

[image]

I want to select all data between noon and 10pm, i.e. rows 1-2 & 4-5. How can I do that?

I tried using [between_time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578836/pick-timestamps-in-certain-time-range-from-a-datetimeindex), but it does not seem to work because (as far as I can tell) the time is a series in the data and not a timestamp. That suggests I need to first convert the series to a timestamp, but [datetime.strptime](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime) does not seem to work because the time is not a string, and neither does [series.to_timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_timestamp.html) (`my_dataframe.iloc[:,0].to_timestamp()` seems to raise an "unsupported Type RangeIndex" error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert your Series (converted [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)) to a [`DatetimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) to use [`DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time) to get the positions of the matching rows, and [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to select them:

```
keep = (pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(my_dataframe['time']))
          .indexer_between_time('12:00', '22:00')
       )
# array([1, 2, 4, 5])

out = my_dataframe.iloc[keep]
```

Output:

```
                time  assists  rebounds  blocks
1  2024-1-1 15:00:00        7         8       7
2  2024-1-1 21:00:00        7        10       7
4  2024-1-2 15:00:00       12         6       5
5  2024-1-2 21:00:00        9         5       8
```

Or, use the datetime as index and [`between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html):

```
out = (my_dataframe.set_index(pd.to_datetime(my_dataframe['time']))
                   .between_time('12:00', '22:00')
      )
```

Output:

```
                                  time  assists  rebounds  blocks
time                                                             
2024-01-01 15:00:00  2024-1-1 15:00:00        7         8       7
2024-01-01 21:00:00  2024-1-1 21:00:00        7        10       7
2024-01-02 15:00:00  2024-1-2 15:00:00       12         6       5
2024-01-02 21:00:00  2024-1-2 21:00:00        9         5       8
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cond = pd.to_datetime(my_dataframe['time']).dt.hour.between(12, 22)
out = my_dataframe[cond]
```

out:

```
                time  assists  rebounds  blocks
1  2024-1-1 15:00:00        7         8       7
2  2024-1-1 21:00:00        7        10       7
4  2024-1-2 15:00:00       12         6       5
5  2024-1-2 21:00:00        9         5       8
```

Comment: That's a quick workaround if you don't have minutes/seconds ;)